# Draw the borders of the selected tile

Tags: leaflet

When I click on the map, a square should be drawn along the borders of the tile that was clicked on.

I know how to get the tile that was clicked:

```
function MyTestFunc1(latlng, zoom) {
    var xtile = parseInt(Math.floor((latlng.lng + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, zoom)));
    var ytile = parseInt(Math.floor((1 - Math.log(Math.tan(latlng.lat * Math.PI / 180) + 1 / Math.cos(latlng.lat * Math.PI / 180)) / Math.PI) / 2 * Math.pow(2, zoom)));
    return "" + zoom + " - " + ytile + " - " + xtile;
}

map.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(MyTestFunc1(e.latlng.wrap(), map.getZoom()));
});
```

I know how to draw a square using coordinates:

```
var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I don't understand how I can get the coordinates of the corners of the resulting tile.

Perhaps there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of how to add a border to a tile.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/**
 * Simple map
 */

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

// click on map
map.on("click", (e) => {
  const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;

  // find image with specific src
  const img = document.querySelector(
    `img[src="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${getTileNumber(lat, lng)}.png"]`
  );
  img.style.border = "2px solid red";
});

// convert lat, lng to tile number
function getTileNumber(lat, lng) {
  const currentZoom = map.getZoom();

  const xtile = parseInt(Math.floor(((lng + 180) / 360) * (1 << currentZoom)));
  const ytile = parseInt(
    Math.floor(
      ((1 -
        Math.log(
          Math.tan((lat * Math.PI) / 180) + 1 / Math.cos((lat * Math.PI) / 180)
        ) /
          Math.PI) /
        2) *
        (1 << currentZoom)
    )
  );
  return `${currentZoom}/${xtile}/${ytile}`;
}
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Of course, this does not create a rectangle over the tile, but maybe you can use something from it ;)

A few hours later and I think we have a solution :)

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/**
 * change tile style when click
 */

// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

map.on("click", (e) => {
  const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
  const zoom = map.getZoom();

  const rectangle = L.rectangle(
    [
      [
        tile2lat(getTileNumber(lat, lng, zoom).split("/")[2], zoom),
        tile2lon(getTileNumber(lat, lng, zoom).split("/")[1], zoom),
      ],
      [
        tile2lat(
          parseInt(getTileNumber(lat, lng, zoom).split("/")[2]) + 1,
          zoom
        ),
        tile2lon(
          parseInt(getTileNumber(lat, lng, zoom).split("/")[1]) + 1,
          zoom
        ),
      ],
    ],
    {
      color: "#ff7800",
      weight: 1,
    }
  ).addTo(map);
});


function tile2lon(x, z) {
  return (x / Math.pow(2, z)) * 360 - 180;
}

function tile2lat(y, z) {
  const n = Math.PI - (2 * Math.PI * y) / Math.pow(2, z);
  return (180 / Math.PI) * Math.atan(0.5 * (Math.exp(n) - Math.exp(-n)));
}

function getTileNumber(lat, lng, zoom) {
  const xtile = parseInt(Math.floor(((lng + 180) / 360) * (1 << zoom)));
  const ytile = parseInt(
    Math.floor(
      ((1 -
        Math.log(
          Math.tan((lat * Math.PI) / 180) + 1 / Math.cos((lat * Math.PI) / 180)
        ) /
          Math.PI) /
        2) *
        (1 << zoom)
    )
  );
  return `${zoom}/${xtile}/${ytile}`;
}
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```